# Beneath snow, under snow, or something else

Tags: prepositions

How can I explain briefly (like in a headline) that the city is covered with snow? Are the following examples correct, or do you suggest something else?

> Istanbul beneath (*the?*) snow (*piles?*)
>   Istanbul under (*the?*) snow (*piles?*)

Comment: How about "Istanbul buried in snow"? (That would suggest quite a lot of snow, though; I'm not sure how much you're actually having.)

Comment: No heavy snow at the moment, but more on the way. Good suggestion BTW.

Comment: *Istanbul under snow* sounds like a perfectly acceptable, snappy headline to me, as does *Instanbul beneath snow*, but I'd prefer the former.

Comment: Instanbul under snow sounds like the snow is somehow attacking Istanbul.

Comment: How often is Istanbul really buried in snow? I can not even remember when I had to describe Oslo (in Norway) as buried in snow... ;)

Comment: "Istanbul snowed in" works as a "headline"...

Comment: If it's for a newspaper; they don't seem to be much concerned about making either grammatically or logically sense in the headlines... "ICE AGE IN ISTANBUL!" would probably sell newspapers. ;)

Comment: @Stein: Oslo doesn't count, they have heated sidewalks.

Comment: For a dramatic headline I'd go: *Istanbul trapped in snow* Oh, look nobody has suggested it.

Comment: Of the two words (and living in what, in any other year, would be "snow country"), I would tend to use "beneath".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could say that the city is *blanketed* in snow.

Comment: Nice one... +1.

Answer (score 5):

"Istanbul Snowed Under" is a short and sweet headline.

Answer (score 3):

For a dramatic eye-catching headline, I'd suggest

> **Istanbul *TRAPPED* in snow!**

For something less sensational any of the the following:

- Istanbul hit by snow
- Istanbul under a layer of snow

For something more literary

- A [mantle of snow](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mantle_1) covers the city of Istanbul
- Istanbul in a mantle of snow

Comment: Just above this line I see "answered Mar 10 at 10:10, edited 10 hours ago". Could this be a sign? :)

Comment: ...and plus 1 BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Snowy Istanbul.
Snow-covered Istanbul.
Snow-wrapped Istanbul.
Snow-bound Istanbul.
Snow-entombed Istanbul.

(in increasing order of severity)

Comment: Snow wrapped and snow entombed?  Is that British?  Never heard those before.

Comment: @Eric: No it's not [British](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_language).

Answer (score 2):

If a city has a lot of rain would you describe it as "under the water"?

I think both "under" and "beneath" suggests really massive amount of snow, so that you have to dig down to find the city under the snow.

I'd say "covered" is more correct.

Comment: Makes sense. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Istanbul is covered in snow.
Istanbul is buried in snow.
Istanbul is a winter wonderland.